# What are the semantics of the parent of the sourceComponent of a loader?

Tags: qt, qml, parent, qtquick2

When I do this:

```
Loader {
    sourceComponent: Item {
        id: toLoad
    }
}
```

then `toLoad` has parent `null` unless I explicitly set a parent on it.

But when I do this:

```
Component {
    id: myComp
    Item {
    }
}

Loader {
    sourceComponent: myComp
}
```

then the item instantiated by the Loader has parent equal to the parent of the Loader.

Is this description I experimentally determined complete and correct, or is there something to add?

If it's correct, then why is there this difference between the two cases?

Answer (score 1):

There is support for implicit conversion from an instance to a component.

So this:

```
Loader {
    sourceComponent: Item {
        id: toLoad
    }
}
```

Is simply the implicit version of this:

```
Loader {
    sourceComponent: Component {
        Item {
            id: toLoad
        }
    }
}
```

When you bind to a property, the value is collected by the "parent" object, but it is not parented to it. The item is not an instance, but a property, and properties are not parented:

```
  property Item name: Item {
    Component.onCompleted: console.log(name.parent) \\ null
  }
```

This changes when the actual component is instantiated, and it is very much parented where it needs to be:

```
  Row {
    Loader {
      sourceComponent: MouseArea {
        id: toLoad
        width: 200
        height: 200
        onClicked: {
          console.log(parent) \\ QQuickLoader(0x2128768)
          console.log(toLoad.parent) \\ QQuickLoader(0x2128768)
        }
      }
    }
    Loader {
      sourceComponent: myComp
    }
  }
  Component {
    id: myComp
    MouseArea {
      width: 200
      height: 200
      onClicked: console.log(parent) // QQuickLoader(0x2128768)
    }
  }
  Component.onCompleted: console.log(toLoad.parent) // ReferenceError: toLoad is not defined
```

As evident from that code, you are not even able to access an id that is in a component from outside that component. So I don't know where you got that null parent, there is no such id on the outside, and on the inside the object will be instantiated and it will definitely have a parent.

Also note that the `Component` is kind of a special case too, as it doesn't even expose the parent, even thou it definitely has one.

Comment: It should be noted and distinguished, that there are parent and visual parent in Qt Quick. They often differs for an object.

Comment: *"There is support for implicit conversion from an instance to a component."* There is no instance. For each property of type `Component` it will parse the code into a component. If it would implicitly convert the instance to a component, you could write something like this:  `sourceComponent: Qt.createComponent("SomeQML.qml").createObject(...)` which will fail with "*Unable to assign QQuickItem to QQmlComponent*". *"Is simply the implicit version of this:"* is correct.

Comment: *"Also note that the Component is kind of a special case too, as it doesn't even expose the parent, even thou it definitely has one."* => Like a `QtObject`, a Component has no visual parent. `Component { parent: ... }` will fail. It might have an parent in the sense of the Qt parent, but no visual parent, and those are everything that counts in QML. The non-visual parent is never exposed.

Comment: Yet, QML only exposes the visual parent, that is the parent item. Which is silly IMO, I mean not exposing the parent for non-visible objects, which can be quite handy. On the previous comment - an implicit conversion can be on semantic level rather than a runtime conversion, which is common in dynamic typed languages. This is also how implicit conversions work in C++, the conversion will not happen if the compiler doesn't know it has to happen, as it will not generate the code. Look it up ;)

Comment: The term `implicit conversion` is not what I mean. It is `from an instance` which I deem semantically wrong, as there never has been an instance to be converted. So if you write it like this, it might imply that you could assign an instance to it, which you can't. In C++ you can assign instances which are implicitly converted into other types if the right constructor is available.

Comment: I am talking about programming language semantics here, not spoken language semantics. It is an instance, because it is declared as such. It is the qml compiler that recognizes what it is, where it is, and inserts the missing stuff for you. Which is exactly how implicit conversions work in C++, you type a `foo(bar)`, the compiler determines foo doesn't take in a bar, but there is baz, which has a constructor that takes in a bar, so `foo(bar)` implicitly becomes `foo(baz(bar))`.

Comment: The same thing happens when you plug an instance where a component should go, it is a "compile time implicit conversion", while the example you provided via `createObject()` doesn't work, because it happens during the runtime, which the runtime doesn't know how to handle, because qml is not statically typed, it can at best attempt a runtime implicit conversion, which fails because there is no such thing implemented. Hopefully that makes it clear now.